# How Do I Insert a Byte[] Into an SQL Server VARBINARY Column

Tags: arrays, sql-server

I have a byte array highlighted below, how do I insert it into a SQL Server database Varbinary column?

```
byte[] arraytoinsert = new byte[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

string sql = 
    string.format
    (
    "INSERT INTO mssqltable (varbinarycolumn) VALUES ({0});",WHATTODOHERE
    );
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

My solution would be to use a parameterised query, as the connectivity objects take care of formatting the data correctly (including ensuring the correct data-type, and escaping "dangerous" characters where applicable):

```
// Assuming "conn" is an open SqlConnection
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mssqltable(varbinarycolumn) VALUES (@binaryValue)", conn))
{
    // Replace 8000, below, with the correct size of the field
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = arraytoinsert;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Edit: Added the wrapping "using" statement as suggested by John Saunders to correctly dispose of the SqlCommand after it is finished with

Comment: Jason, could you please put a using statement around "SqlCommand cmd = new ..."? Otherwise, I'll feel obligated to downvote, and I'd hate that.

Comment: If the column is VARBINARY(MAX), then replace 8000 with -1, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/e61f0616-0866-4f3f-aeba-6a76e144e169/

Answer (score 84):

Try this:

```
"0x" + BitConverter.ToString(arraytoinsert).Replace("-", "")
```

Although you should really be using a parameterised query rather than string concatenation of course...

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer, why should I be using a parameterised query?

Comment: Minimal here, but parameterised queries can be compiled and then cached, saving the cost of compilation with each subsequent query. They also protect against SQL injection attacks. Finally, you can set the value of the parameter to the byte array directly and avoid the BitConverter stuff...

Comment: Don't think working with VARBINARIES like this is good idea in general. SQL Server allows very large VARBINARIES (was it 2 Gb?) and that would probably not "scale very well" with this method. Can't assess if this would be a problem in this particular case, so I'm leaving off the -1 for now.

Comment: Finally an answer to this question instead of 'you should use parameters..'
There are reasons for not using parameters - e.g. exceeding the 2,100 parameters in single query.

Comment: +1 to counteract @peSHIr.
The OP didn't mention large files scalability, it asked `WHATTODOHERE` in the text query.

Comment: @DavidM if you convert the bytes array to string, how is this used in a query without using parameters?

Answer (score 1):

No problem if all the arrays you are about to use in this scenario are small like in your example.

If you will use this for large blobs (e.g. storing large binary files many Mbs or even Gbs in size into a `VARBINARY`) then you'd probably be much better off using specific support in SQL Server for reading/writing subsections of such large blobs. Things like [`READTEXT`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187365.aspx) and [`UPDATETEXT`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), or in current versions of SQL Server `SUBSTRING`.

For more information and examples see either my 2006 article in .NET Magazine (["BLOB + Stream = BlobStream"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cc307758.aspx), in Dutch, with complete source code), or an English translation and generalization of this [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/LobStreamFrameworkPart1.aspx) by Peter de Jonghe. Both of these are linked from [my weblog](http://peshir.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!FEC8DE0C9895E736!1353.entry).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, very simple and efficient solution:
What i did was actually use a parameter instead of basic placeholder, created a SqlParameter object and used another existing execution method. For e.g in your scenario:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO mssqltable (varbinarycolumn) VALUES (@img)";
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("img", arraytoinsert); //where img is your parameter name in the query
ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, param);
```

This should work like a charm, provided you have an open sql connection established.

Answer (score -1):

check this image link for all steps
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0-Ll2y6vo_sQ29hYndnbGZVZms

STEP1: I created a field of type varbinary in table

STEP2: I created a stored procedure to accept a parameter of type sql_variant

STEP3: In my front end asp.net page, I created a sql data source parameter of object type

```
        <tr>
        <td>
            UPLOAD DOCUMENT</td>
        <td>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsFileUploadConn" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: %>" 
                InsertCommand="ph_SaveDocument"     
               InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="DocBinaryForm" Type="Object" />
                </InsertParameters>

             </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

STEP 4: In my code behind, I try to upload the FileBytes from FileUpload Control via this stored procedure call using a sql data source control

```
      Dim filebytes As Object
      filebytes = FileUpload1.FileBytes()
      sqldsFileUploadConn.InsertParameters("DocBinaryForm").DefaultValue = filebytes.ToString
      Dim uploadstatus As Int16 = sqldsFileUploadConn.Insert()

               ' ... code continues ... '
```