# Insert byte[] to blob column in Informix DB using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, blob, informix

Just like these links

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267159/sql-informix-how-do-i-add-a-blob-when-doing-an-insert-using-the-net-c-s/16790499#16790499/)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319858/informix-c-how-do-i-properly-set-unset-a-blob-field)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467562/operations-on-blob-data-in-informix)

[**Link 4**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267159/sql-informix-how-do-i-add-a-blob-when-doing-an-insert-using-the-net-c-s)

Am also unable to insert only byte[] related operations on my informix database. I tried many ways and gone through IBM site. but no where its explained "how to use byte[] to insert into blob column using c#".

"LINK 4" is very helpful. but am facing problem with this code.

```
Error: The %0 enumeration value, %1, is invalid.
At line: blob.Open(IfxSmartLOBOpenMode.ReadWrite);
if i use cmd.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter()).Value = byteuploaded`;
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
protected void uploadfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string extension;
        // checks if file exists
        if (!_imageUpload.HasFile)
        {
            _resultLbl.Text = "Please, Select a File!";
            return;
        }
        // checks file extension
        extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_imageUpload.FileName).ToLower();
        if (!extension.Equals(".jpg") && !extension.Equals(".jpeg") && !extension.Equals(".png"))
        {
            _resultLbl.Text = "Only image files (.JPGs and .PNGs) are allowed.";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // =========   This is not working   ==============
            string sqlQuery = "insert into db95:TestBlobUpload (id ,fileblob) values('2', 'two');";
            // =========   This is working properly  ==============
            //string sqlQuery = "insert into db95:TestBlobUpload (id ,filetext) values('4',?);";
            string connString = "Database=db95;Host=172.16.XX.XX;Server=vsXXXX;Service=88;Protocol=onsoctcp;UID=ed;Password=ca94;";
            using (this.connection = new IfxConnection(connString))
            {
                this.connection.Open();
                using (this.cmd = new IfxCommand(sqlQuery, this.connection))
                {
                    // Start a local transaction
                    this.trans = this.connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Unspecified);
                    // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
                    this.cmd.Transaction = trans;
                    try
                    {


                        IfxBlob byteuploaded = new IfxBlob(this.connection);
                        byteuploaded.Read(_imageUpload.FileBytes);

                        // =========   BOTH OF THESE are not working   ==============
                        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter()).Value = data;// System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter()).Value = byteuploaded;// _imageUpload.FileBytes;

                        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        // commiting the transaction
                        this.cmd.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //this.cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
                this.connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

am using this dll as a reference and using IBM.Data.Informix;

[image]

particularly am unable to add byte[] to blob columns. All other insert/update/delete operations i can do.

Any help?

I even upgraded to ibm_data_server_driver_package_win64_v10.1.exe & clientsdk.4.10.FC1DE.WIN.exe

But am facing problems with dll compatibility. unable to load'XX.XX.dll" exception is comin.

I even tried to execute the insert query using

```
INSERT INTO db95@vsXXXX:testblobupload (fileblob) 
   VALUES (db95@vsXXXX:FILETOBLOB('C:\tmp\Untitled.png', 'client'));
```

and facing error as

```
ERROR: Smart-large-object error.
Error Code: -9810.
Smart Large Objects: No sbspace number specified.
```

Comment: You did make it work ? I have the same problems

Answer (score 1):

This is not your c# app. It's the Informix environment needs to be setup for large smart objects. I think it basically specifies space to use on server. I don't know anything else. If you return the isam error code it would be this

-12053  Smart Large Objects: No sbspace number specified.

No default sbspace was f ound, and the caller has not specified an sbspace
to use.

Either specify the smart-large-object space name in the
smart-large-object function call or set the SBSPACENAME onconfig
file parameter to the name of a valid smart-large-object space.

Answer (score 1):

We can include blob fields in specific sbspace using the `PUT IN` clause.

If we use `connection.GetIfxBlob()` without specifying the table name and column name, the blob field will be included in the default sbspace set in the onconfig `SBSPACENAME`, and if not set will give the error `SQLERR-9810 ISAM ERR-12053`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that the best way of save Informix Blob is using this function :

```
    string insertSql = string.Format("insert into \"{0}\" (sbfotoint,NmArqBlob) values (?,?);", this.table);

        using (var command = new IfxCommand(insertSql, this.connection))
        {
            this.connection.Open();
            SetRole();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter()).Value = CreateIfxBlob(entidade.SBlob);
            command.Parameters.Add(new IfxParameter()).Value = entidade.NomeArquivo;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.connection.Close();
        }

private IfxBlob CreateIfxBlob(byte[] data)
    {
        IfxBlob blob = connection.GetIfxBlob(this.table, "sbfotoint");
        blob.Open(IfxSmartLOBOpenMode.ReadWrite);
        blob.Write(data);
        blob.Close();
        return blob;
    }
```