# How to get image size which is stored in varbinary format in database using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

All the image are stored in database in `varbinary` format. Now, I want the list of  images whose size is less than 1MB. Is there anyway to get the image size when it is in varbinary format? If we get number of bytes using `DATALENGTH()` in SQL Server, will this be equal to the image size when that `varbinary` data is converted into image file?

Comment: "will this be equal to the image size when that varbinary data is converted into image file?" - probably. But to truly answer that, we'd have to know *how you converted the image files to store them in the database in the first place*.

Comment: Exactly, when [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7324190/3682162) is ready out there on SO.

Comment: First, the image was converted to 'Base64 format, then from Base64 I convert it into byte. This byte is stored in Database in varbinary format.

Comment: I was worried that there would be unnecessary conversions here and your comment suggests that there are. Depending on exactly what you've done, you've possible bloated up the amount of space used in the database by 4/3.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for pointing that out. Is there any other efficient way we can store images? How does storing the image in byte[] bloat up the amount of space used in database?