# How insert Image from a directory path in my computer into SQL Server binary column with T-SQL with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to insert an image from a path in my computer (for example `D:\th.jpg`) into a MS SQL Server binary column with T-SQL and choose specific row with WHERE clause.

This column's name is `Image` with a datatype of `varbinary(MAX)` and my table name is `Recipes`.

Comment: Where's you c# code? How are you reading the image and inserting it into the command?

Comment: Note that BULK INSERT and OPENROWSET ... BULK read files on the SQL Server, or in network locations accessible from the SQL Server.  Not from where your client program is running.

Comment: Is this `D:\ ` drive connected to the machine on which SQL Server is running? A remote SQL Server **cannot** grab files from your own local `D:\ ` drive. ....

Comment: I have edited my question and added to it. And my program and data base are locally running.

Comment: Can you use c# to write as well as read?  in my opinion, opening SQL engine to access disks is something to avoid.  Something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324190/how-to-store-images-to-a-varbinarymax-column

Comment: Sorry, I made a big mistake and I changed my question completely and I answered it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update dbo.Recipes
Set Image = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\th.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) Image)
Where Id = 13
```