# C# Encryption Android Decryption

Tags: c#, android, encryption

I encrypt a string in c# (RijndaelManaged), which returns a byte array.

I want to save that byte array to a database in order to get it decrypted later in the android device.

I have tried converting it to base64 in c#, But as I understand android doesnt support base64 decoding before API8.

Is there another way saving the byte array in the DB, so I can later fetch it and decrypt it on android?

10X

Comment: Why do you need to convert to Base64? You can store byte arrays in most databases.

Comment: Android devices can seldom access databases C# applications access, they need web-services in the middle.

Comment: The database will be converted to sqlite database (From MySql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Java Base64 decoders everywhere http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/ , add it to your Android project and you're off.

If not, just translate each byte into two hexadecimal digits in C#, and then back in Android. It's very easy to do so yourself.

Comment: I`m Trying the java class, but the result is different then what originally was created in the C# code. I am trying to figure out why is that.

Comment: I say don't worry about it at all. Convert to hex and forget about it.

Comment: I have tried both (Base64 and Hex), and from some reason some of the bytes I get in android are negative, while the original c# byte array is all positive. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, make sure you're using unsigned integers (and shorts) when building the byte value again.

Comment: Ok - did the Java Base64 solution. 10X :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

you can implement the base64 encoding yourself on both sides so that you can be sure, you can see example code of how to implement Base64 encoding  and decoding in languages like c, C++, java, and javascript on [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64)

Yes, if you are using SQL Server, you can use [VarBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

you can read more about insert a byte array into database in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064121/how-do-i-insert-a-byte-into-an-sql-server-varbinary-column)

You can insert [BLOB Data in SQLITE](http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm) and [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html) too

Comment: I am using MySql, which be later will be converted to sqlite.

Comment: Check [How do i store and retrieve a blob from sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite) to see how to store blo data in sqllite