# How to save .rar or .zip file in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a **c#** windows application and i want to save and retrive a **rar** or **zip** file to sql server.Is there any way to insert a .rar or .zip file to SQL Server and get it back again?
Please Help Me.

Comment: Have you tried storing it as BLOB?

Comment: You can save it as a binary datatype.

Comment: i have no idea how to do it using blob or binary....please any one of you can provide me code for this...

Comment: @BeingSufiyan you cant get the code, but you can get the resources to read .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms131092(v=sql.100).aspx  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064121/how-do-i-insert-a-byte-into-an-sql-server-varbinary-column

Answer (score 2):

Create a column of type `varbinary(max)`. In C# you can insert/select the content as a `byte[]`. You can use `File.ReadAllBytes` or `File.WriteAllBytes` to get the file content as `byte[]` or write it.

And remember: *you can always use Google, too!*

Comment: Thank You Sir...i will try it....and back again here...when i m done doing this...

Comment: I'll remove the downvote if you change "binary" to "varbinary(max)". Binary datatype in SQL Server is for fixed length binary columns only. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188362.aspx

Comment: Oh, right you are :-)