# How to pass Byte Array in a Query using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to insert bytes of byte array in the database. using following code.

```
String query = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO [Documents]
                              ([InsertedBy], [DocumentName], [Document])
                              VALUES
                              ('{0}','{1}',{2})",
                              insertedBy, docName, docBytes);

Cmd.CommandText = query;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Following exception is occured:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name. Incorrect syntax near ''.

I'm not getting what the reason is.

Comment: What are the types of these columns? What are the values of your `insertedBy`, `docName` and `docBytes` exactly?

Comment: insertedBy is int, documentname is varchar(100) and Document is VarBinary(max)

Comment: I would always insert the varbinary as a parameter in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088630/812598, since it seems to be a raw `byte[]` type by it's name.

Comment: You should not code SQL this way, it is susceptible to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack).

Comment: I second that. Don't forge SQL queries yourself. Use ADO.NET or some similar library that do the translation to the underlying Database dialect

Comment: GOROS is absolutely right, that thing really worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use string concatenation or string functions to make parametrized queries.

Also, because (I suspect that) `docBytes` is a `byte[]`, string concatenation will not have the results that you hope for.

Here is how I would do it:

```
private static void InsertDocument(SqlCommand cmd, int insertedBy, string docName, byte[] docBytes)
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Documents]
                        ([InsertedBy], [DocumentName], [Document])
                        VALUES
                        (@insertedBy,@docName,@docBytes)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("insertedBy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = insertedBy;
    // Note: consider using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("docName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = docName;
    // Note: -1 maps to the nvarchar(max) length;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("docBytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = docBytes;

    // The following call presupposes that the associated `SqlConnection` is open
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `insertedBy` column is an `int`, you don't need to use single quotes with it. Because you are try to insert characters to your `int` typed column.

Just use it like;

```
string query = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO [Documents]
                              ([InsertedBy], [DocumentName], [Document])
                              VALUES
                              ({0},'{1}',{2})",
                              insertedBy, docName, docBytes);
```

But since we don't know your values, this is the only suggestion I have.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would assume `docBytes` could be a problem too, e.g. if it's a `byte[]`. The error message in the question might indicate something like that.

Comment: same error even after removing the quotations, this is for sure that those quotation are not the cause of problem