# saving bytearray to VarBinary column in SQL Server inserts only one byte

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, varbinary

I have a following problem - I'm trying to save `byte[]` to database and I just figured out that it works for one byte only.

I have number of floats that I convert to byte[] and use that as a parameter:

```
param = new SqlParameter(name, type, ((byte[])value).Length);
```

type is `VarBinary`, value is the byte array.

I add that parameter to my `SqlCommand` and just before it gets executed the whole byte array "sits" in that parameter and `_msize` of that parameter is correct (20 for 20 bytes I assume is correct). My SQL Server shows me only 1 byte saved, also trying to retrieve it back I'm getting only one byte. My column is `VarBinary(200)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: think the answer in this post will do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064121/how-do-i-insert-a-byte-into-an-sql-server-varbinary-column

Comment: Show the code where you set the parameter value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a stored procedure, and you've defined your parameter as just `varbinary` - you'll get a default length of **1 byte** as per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx):

> When n is **not specified** in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the **default length is 1**. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

So if you have a stored procedure with

```
@MyData VARBINARY
```

then you have just one single byte - you need to change that to something like

```
@MyData VARBINARY(200)
```

or something else that's suitable for you

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: yes - in C# - but what if that C# code calls a T-SQL stored procedure that uses that parameter *without* a length? C# has the length and all - but inside the T-SQL stored procedure, you get **1 byte** of `varbinary` data ....