# How to view pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I save file with  telerik RadAsyncUpload (asp):

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" Localization-Select="select file" Localization-Remove="delete" 
                    Width="10px" ID="RadAsyncUpload1" MultipleFileSelection="Automatic" AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf" 
                    ControlObjectsVisibility="None" EnableFileInputSkinning="true" />
```

in code  behind I do:

```
byte[] bytes = null;

    if (RadAsyncUpload1 != null)
    {
        foreach (UploadedFile file in RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles)
        {
            bytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
            WinPic.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
            BinaryImage.DataValue = bytes;
        }
    }
```

and save in sql in column data type: varbinary(MAX).

for view the file I use on:

```
<telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="BinaryImage" Width="600px" Height="600px" 
                ResizeMode="Fit" AutoAdjustImageControlSize="true" DecoratedControls="All" />
```

but my problem is, when I view file type pdf, it's dont Work.
I see the picture like so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltoFF.png)

Hope your help
Tanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDF is not a supported DataValue of RadBinaryImage](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radbinaryimage-the-provided-binary-data-may-not-be-valid-image-or-may-contains-unknown-header#cUJlgo8ys0-YtjptpXRYRw)

You can also read further down that thread for another solution on how to display the PDF file.

This is how I've done it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Similar to what is in the telerik thread, I open a new window and do a binary write of the byte array.

Comment: I get from sql in DataSet like so: 
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["btPassportImage"] what What do I need to fill the variables: 'fileName' and 'bytes'?

Comment: `bytes` should be your byte array and `fileName` can be any string

Comment: Thank! It's good!!
1.Could I know, when I get the file in byte, which type it (jpeg/pdf...)?
2.How could I open the pdf in new tab?

Comment: the easiest way I open PDF in a new tab is through javascript.. `window.open("url");` THEN, in the `Page_Load` for that page, I get the byte[] and execute that code.

Comment: in regards to getting file type from byte[], take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature?lq=1

Comment: for reference, look at this for storing your byte[] in SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064121/how-do-i-insert-a-byte-into-an-sql-server-varbinary-column

Comment: it also looks like you should be able to use that solution in a RadWindow: http://www.telerik.com/forums/rad-window---opening-pdf#DO_oceS7g0KcUSdX4yKq0g

Comment: Could you show me the code that open the byte in new tab?

Comment: all you have to do is assign a javascript function to execute: `window.open("URL to new aspx page");` In the Page_Load of the new aspx page, query out the byte[] you are saving to SQL and then execute the code in my solution.

Comment: It's execlent!
Thenk you